# Using the value from one column to slice the value of another column to generate a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, text-processing

My real pandas dataframe has 500,000 rows and 20 columns. I want to use the information from one column to slice the values from another column and return a new column with this information. Below is a simplified version of my dataframe and desired output. I need to use the value held in 'location' to know where to slice 'sentence' to return the information I am seeking to analyze 'animal'. For simplicity the location value and the location value minus 3 gives the splicing coordinates: for location value of 6 desired information (animal) is sentence[3:6].

I have been struggling with different methods including iteration (`iterrows` and `itertuples`) over the rows (which someone metioned is "rarely correct"), but I am concerned that I do not know how to do this properly as other say “NEVER iterate” and stress issues with it, and to "exhaust other options".  But I do not know the options and as far as I gotten so far, slicing is not as straight forward? What is the safest way and most professional way to do this? I don't care about speed.  I care about accuracy.

```
my_dict = {'sentence': [ 'Thedogwearsred', 'Thatcatatethebird', 'Thebigratstruggledwithpandas', 'Thebestdogwassmall'], 'location' = [6, 7, 9, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
Out[50]: 
                       sentence  location
0                Thedogwearsred         6
1             Thatcatatethebird         7
2  Thebigratstruggledwithpandas         9
3            Thebestdogwassmall        10
```

Desired output:

```
Out[52]: 
                       sentence  location animal
0                Thedogwearsred         6    dog
1             Thatcatatethebird         7    cat
2  Thebigratstruggledwithpandas         9    rat
3            Thebestdogwassmall        10    dog
```

Comment: Does this mean that the animals' names will always be only **three letters long**?

Comment: Yes, three letters long always.

Comment: ```python  
def process_row(row, offset=3):
    label = row['sentence']
    pos = row['location']
    animal = label[pos-offset:pos]
    return animal
df['animal'] = df.apply(lambda x: process_row(x, offset=3), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['animal'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['sentence'][x['location'] - 3 : x['location']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you all!  Aryrez's answer didn't work for me, until I took out the .str, as is done in the duplicate answer.'df['animal'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['sentence'][x['location'] - 3 : x['location']], axis=1)'

Comment: @MelBel88 Right, my bad. The `.str` is needed only on a `pd.Series` while `x` is a single string. I've edited it for the next generations :)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm learning lots here.  Appreciate it!